# Small PHP Code - Causing Server Load? Help Optimize

Tags: php, optimization, random

I have this small bit of code (listed at the end of this message), that runs on page load. We get around 50,000 UNIQUE visitors per day (not counting repeats). It could be coincidental, but ever since implementation, there have been random server load issues.

**So what I'm asking is...**

**1)** Can someone confirm/deny whether or not the below code can in fact cause issues?

**2)** Can this be optimized?

**Just fyi:**

**--** I have stuck this function in the HEADER file of a WordPress layout.

**--** It is called 10+ times in the footer

**--** It is a VPS server using NGINX

**--** I have not checked the logs just yet

The code's purpose...
We specify a percentage to the function that tells the code to display a string that percent of the time (so if we put 60, then it means the string should show up 60% of the time). Each entry in the footer generates its own random number.

**The code:**

```
function writeRndString($theString, $percent) {
$randno = rand(1,100);

if($randno <= (int)$percent) {
    echo "Random String: " . $theString;
    echo "\n\n";
}
}
```

Comment: The code does not seems very complexe. Even if you are calling this function 10+ times, it should be ok. Did you take a look at your PHP log ? Apache log ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have not checked the logs just yet (but I'm definitely going to momentarily). Btw, it's running through NGINX (I'll amend the post with that info).

Comment: My proposed solution: write all the strings out, hidden with CSS, and use JavaScript to reveal them based on random percentages. Then you can cache your page, which will be the same for all visitors, and the user's CPU does the work :)

Comment: That is a good solution, but we actually don't want users to be able to see what all of the strings actually are if they were to view the source code (we may resort to it though if we don't figure it out). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple function, should be fast, even if you call it several times. Even with 50000 daily, which is about 2 pages per second.

If you can, simply remove it for a few minutes and check the server load. It could be called a lot more times than you assume :)

Answer (score 0):

Maby....

You forgot a $ on: echo "Random String: " . theString;
And alitte bether maby, don't use variables you don't need in fact.
maby also use return

```
function writeRndString($theString, $percent) {
    if (rand(1, 100) <= (int) $percent) {
        return "Random String: " . $theString . "\n\n";
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
echo "blablabla" . writeRndString($x, $y);
?>
```

Comment: Whoops -- my apologies. I had edited the variable name before posting it. Often times, I use odd variable names (such as "pork", "poop", etc) so I was just making it look a bit less weird. Anyway, it's correct in the original code. Thanks though.